# Can we ionise a gas with concentrated white light?

Tags: energy, photon-emission

I don't yet have the backround to answer this question :
Does a visible white light enough dense could partially ionise a gas at macroscopic scale ?

What I think knowing :
Quantified photon energy can bring atom's electron to upper energy levels.
High enough photon can ionise an atom and realise the electrons that absorbed it.
Rapid accumulation of precise photons can also lead to an ionisation.
At macroscopic scale the atom will loose or gain energy before reimeting/absorbing another photons by colliding with others.

So more precise but certainly false question would be :
Does, with some time, the energy could be "stocked" from collision in the gas in such a way that some ionisation occure by the fact we continuously inject energy in it (if we imagine perfect reflective surfaces too) ? If yes how far this process could go ?
So would it be interesting to use white light in order to maximise the possibility of absoption (due to the multiple energy step ("not that quantified") of atoms at macroscopic scale) instead of precise wavelength in order to ionise efficiently the gas ?

Maybe those effect are absolutly meaningless in front of energy needed.

I'm sorry if i'm unclear, do not hesitate to correct me or ask for precision about my mishunderstoodment of the subject. That would really help !

If you have any suggestions about an atteignable law (for a 1st year student), it would be really welcome !
Good continuation !

Comment: If "wide spectrum light that appears white to the human eye" is a sufficient synonym for "white light", a nuclear weapon in atmosphere would be an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, technically it is possible, but the mechanism would be different.

To start with, instead of using the term "dense" light, the proper term would be "high-intensity" light. Since light is an electromagnetic field, high intensity means that the electric field at a given point also has a high amplitude. If this amplitude is high enough, it can strip the electrons from the molecules or atoms in the air, producing plasma. However, creating such a field with a white light source can be challenging. Nonetheless, it is possible to achieve this with pulsed lasers. You can watch a demonstration of this process on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-adpzFBuMeY&ab_channel=WuZet).

Answer (score 1):

What @Noct describes is (I believe) multiphoton ionization. However, optical radiation can cause air ionization at (much) lower intensity through the avalanche mechanism (https://www.rp-photonics.com/laser_induced_breakdown.html).

Comment: Hi @akmeteli. It is believed that there are many processes involved besides multiphoton ionization. As far as I know, those are extensively studied for purpose of laser-induced breakdown spectroscopy in gaseous media, or to describe light filamentation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filament_propagation). For example, those two reports are describing the involved effects: https://cds.cern.ch/record/1690534/files/CERN-NPA-67-7.pdf (1967), https://aip.scitation.org/doi/am-pdf/10.1063/1.4922076 (2015).  As you can read there, we still don't understand the mechanism fully.

Comment: @Noct :  Actually, you did not mention any specific mechanism of laser-induced breakdown in gas (that is why I added the words "I believe" in my answer). The reason I was not quite happy with your answer was that your phrase "If this amplitude is high enough, it can strip the electrons from the molecules or atoms in the air, producing plasma." seems to imply a mechanism that could ionize a single atom or a molecule, and multiphoton ionization can do just that, whereas avalanche is a collective effect in gas (cntd)

Comment: @Noct : My understanding is avalanche can provide ionization at a much lower intensity that any one-atom mechanism, such as multiphoton ionization. If you don't think this is true, please provide a specific reference, not long articles where it is not clear what I am supposed to look for.

Comment: @akmeteli: I apologize for using a vague statement, but the process is complex and hard to explain briefly without oversimplifying. I included links to detailed commentaries to make up for it. Regarding your citation, RP Encyclopedia refers to the avalanche process in a solid-state medium with free electrons. While the avalanche process can occur in gases, it requires initiation as described in relevant publications. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @Noct : RP mentions air several times. As for the initial electrons of the avalanche, they may be created, e.g., by cosmic rays.